# Why won't the images appear in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, image

In this code, the images won't appear once I run it in the browser. I have tried different browsers  and different ways to sort the image. Could you tell me why this is happening and how I will be able to fix this because I have been trying for days now. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Traffic Light Sequence</title>
<body>
<h2>Manuel Traffic Light Sequence</h2>
<img id="light" src="C:\Users\Mrs Afolabi\Documents\Computing\lights\red.gif">
<button type="button" onClick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
<script>
var list = [
    "C:\Users\Mrs Afolabi\Documents\Computing\lights\green.gif",
    "C:\Users\Mrs Afolabi\Documents\Computing\lights\amber.gif",
    "C:\Users\Mrs Afolabi\Documents\Computing\lights\red.gif"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() 
{
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == list.length) index = 0;
    var image = document.getElementById('light');
    image.src=list[index];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am guessing because of the space in the folder name. try to replace it with %20

Comment: You should close the head tag before the body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title> Traffic Light Sequence</title>
</head>

<body>


<h2>Manuel Traffic Light Sequence</h2>


<img id="light" src="red.gif">


<button type="button" onClick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>


<script>

    var list = [

        "red.gif",

        "green.gif",

        "amber.gif"

    ];

    var index = 0;

    function changeLights() {

        index = index + 1;

        if (index == list.length) index = 0;

        var image = document.getElementById('light');

        image.src = list[index];

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've cleaned up the code a little. Note that the `full path` has been removed from the images.

Where ever the HTML file is located if the images are located directly next to the HTML file then they do not need an absolute path (`c:/...`). Instead relative paths should be used. So assuming the HTML file is found at `C:\Users\Mrs Afolabi\Documents\Computing\lights\index.html` then the following code below should work as it can easily find the `.gif` files.

Comment: You still forgot to close the `<head>`.

Comment: Thank you, good catch. Though browsers will auto close <head> if it is still open before <body> opens.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really helpful. The images now appear and the code runs smoothly :)

Answer (score 0):

Natively there's no permission to access this kind of URL (from user's computer) that starts of `file://`, `C://`, etc... (in any web browser)

If your file is located at some directory in computer, then you can input the files you'll use that are in the same directory, like:

`src/styles.css`, `file.png`, etc